# How to ignore vertical line in laptop screen?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

i have a red vertical line in my laptop screen and i want to ignore it
or re-scale my screen so it skips the red vertical line
something like it splits the screen by that line like that

- "vert ical"
- "lin e"
- "i s"
- "stil l"
- "ther e"

so the line will be there but wont have any effect 
can you guide me ?

P.S i have tried fixing it physically but it has failed

Comment: That's not possible. You need to repair your screen.

Comment: do you get my idea ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said it's not possible. Laptops screens don't work like that. You can't re-scale two different parts of the screen.

Comment: aha
then thanks for your help :)
i hope you are wrong and someone can  give us out of the box idea :)

Comment: If this is for Linux, and you're using a compositing window manager, you might be able to write a custom window manager plugin that will avoid drawing over that line. But performance is going to suck, and it's probably going to be cheaper and less hassle to just get a new monitor or new laptop.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#axzz3wyy9KP2o  Let me know when you figure out how to skip a line.  Other wise just buy a new monitor like DavidPostill said.